# Version control with multiple versions

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I have a general version control question. I have recently written an application and have plans to build upon my current work with new features.
 My intention is to end with two different applications `("my application", and "my application plus")`, both based on the same core code, but one of the versions having more features built in.
My question is, is there a way to have a version control setup to have two different repositories (I suppose) but one of the repositories references the other.
So basically if I change one of the core elements in one application it will change it in both.

Branching might be the answer, but I always thought branching was used to section of a bit of code with the intention to merge it back in later without disrupting or breaking the build. My scenario is a little different.

Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend to separate versioning and variants, i.e. realize your variants with different (build) configurations - not with different software modules.

Comment: Right, or have the core functionality in a core library and the add-ons in a separate repo which links with the core library.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

I used the following strategy on a recent project which had about 5 concurrent developers at its peak, and it has worked well. The `base` code in our case is a core proprietary product, and the `plus` was a client's customisation of that `base` code.

We had a project space for `base` like this;

```
repo/
- base/
 + trunk
 + branches
 + tags
```

We created project space for `plus` alongside base in the same repository;

```
repo/
-base/
 + branches
 + tags
 + trunk

-plus/
 + branches
 + tags
 [new trunk will go here]
```

Use `svn copy` to clone `base/trunk` to `plus/trunk`.

`base` and `plus` now share a common ancestry. `plus` is kept up-to-date by periodically merging `base/trunk` into `plus/trunk`. And by convention we never merged from plus back to base.

[image: Fork Strategy]

The hardest part (I found) was ensuring developers remained disciplined when committing. It is easy to end up in a mess if you start committing what should be `base` code into `plus` with the view to port it back later. The merges were usually very straight forward.

For the record I would not do this in svn again, I would use git. I've described it in svn terms simply because i've done it before.

Incidentally, a `branch` can be used for several different purposes - feature branches, hot fixes, release integration, vendor branches... all branches, but by convention they mean different things. What I've described is still a branch in a way - just one that doesn't by convention reintegrate with its original trunk. Aka a fork.

Answer (score -1):

Normally, you would use a system that helps with branching (like `git`) and keep separate branches (ex: master, master-plus). Every release, you would `git rebase` (or `git merge`) changes from your basic app into the plus version.

PS: You could alo do the same with some kind of a plugin method and two repos

Answer (score -1):

If your base application is written already and you intend to implement extended version of it I recommend you to think about submodules which is a feature of Git (check it out here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). It might be good solution for entire application or only for the core of it. Consider using it.